# How to Create table with Row and column in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html-table

I need some advise on creating a dynamic JavaScript table with the following condition:

1. Every row will have 3 column
2. Number of row will depends on how many data in an array
3. Also to delete a column value based on sequence

Here is some Screenshot

I have 4 data in a array

### Update

For people who don't what I'm trying to achieve is that a button that insert a column  in sequence and when the column has 3 it will move to next row.

[image: Initial row creation]

Button click once

[image]

Button click once more

[image]

Button click once more

[image]

Comment: Would you like to share your initial attempt and explain where is it that you got stuck?

Comment: You can create a table with a specific id, than create a cycle that appends each data into the array to the table as a row.

Comment: use cloning in javascript

Comment: @user2314737 hi i was wondering is this possible to achieve

Comment: quick demo, is that what you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/o0mLc738/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible for instance using Javascript's `table.insertRow` and `table.insertCell` (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_table_insertrow.asp)

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Click the button to add a new row at the first position of the table and then add cells and content.</p>

<table id="myTable">
<tr id="row_0">
<td>0,0</td>
</tr>

</table><br>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
row_nr=0;
col_nr=1;
function myFunction() {
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var row = document.getElementById("row_"+row_nr);
    var cell = row.insertCell(col_nr);
    cell.innerHTML = row_nr+","+col_nr;
    col_nr++;
    if (col_nr %3==0) {
      col_nr=0;
      row_nr++;
      var row = table.insertRow(row_nr);
      row.setAttribute("id", "row_"+row_nr);
    }

}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The modulo in (%3) can be changed to the desired length of rows.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/user2314737/8k11vzyu/1/

[image]

And here is with delete button:

HTML

```
<p>Click the button to add a new row at the first position of the table and then add cells and content.</p>
<table id="myTable">
    <tr id="row_0">
        <td>0,0</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br>
<button onclick="addCell()">Add</button>
<button onclick="removeCell()">Remove</button>
```

JS

```
row_nr = 0;
col_nr = 0;
row_length = 3;

function addCell() {
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var row = document.getElementById("row_" + row_nr);
    col_nr++;
    if (col_nr % row_length == 0) {
        col_nr = 0;
        row_nr++;
        row = table.insertRow(row_nr);
        row.setAttribute("id", "row_" + row_nr);
    }
    var cell = row.insertCell(col_nr);
    cell.innerHTML = row_nr + "," + col_nr;
    cell.setAttribute("id", "cell_" + row_nr + "_" + "col_nr");
}

function removeCell() {
    var row = document.getElementById("row_" + row_nr);
    row.deleteCell(col_nr);
    if (col_nr == 0) {
        col_nr = row_length-1;
        row_nr--;
    } else {
        col_nr--;
    }
}
```

Here is the updated Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/user2314737/8k11vzyu/6/

Comment: Thanks for the answer this is what i wanted can i ask one more is that i also will be needing a remove just like how the adding it will remove starting from the last 

I have done some research i use the same method by using deleteRow but how do i get the last id of the table 

Thanks Appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't understand the data you have provided.
But based on what I understood:

```
 function remove(obj){
    obj.innerHTML=""; 
}


 function createTable(var arr){
    var tab="<table>";
    for(var i=0;i<ar.length/3;i++){
       tab+="<tr>";
       for(var j=0;j<3;j++)
           tab+='<td onclick="remove(this);">'+arr[i+j]+'</td>';
       tab+="</tr>";
     }
    if(arr.length%3!=0){
      tab+='<tr>'; 
      for(var i=0;i<3;i++)
         if(i<arr.length)
              tab+='<td onclick="remove(this);">'+arr[i+j]+'</td>';
         else
               tab+='<td></td>';
      tab+='</tr>';
    }
    tab+="</table>"
    document.getElementById("Boh").innerHTML=tab;
    }

    }
```